# Accessing TimelineJS data structure

Tags: javascript, timeline.js

I have a data structure that I transform into a format that TimelineJS can use. My data structure has the same number of slides as in the timeline, but it has more info than displayed in the timeline. Also, info in my data structure is not in the same order as how TimelineJS presents it as TimelineJS sorts the data by time before rendering the timeline.

For any given slide visible in the timeline, I want to access data from my original data structure. So, given http://example.com/timeline#22, I want to get some data out from my data structure which resulted in slide 22 in the timeline. Since the timeline has sorted my data structure, I don't know which element in my data array is what is showing up as #22 in the timeline. I have wracked my brains but can't figure out a solution.

One way would be to figure out where TimelineJS generates the final data structure that is rendered on the screen and make a copy of it so I can access it. Seems like the data are stored in `VMM.Timeline.DataObj.data_template_obj.timeline` but I can't figure out where to access it. Any guidance would be welcome.